# Setting lucene jar files in java classpath

Tags: java, lucene, classpath

I'm new to lucene and is having trouble getting started.

Following the beginners guide at http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_3_0/demo.html i'm trying to set the classpath, copying the syntax from http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/tooldocs/win32/classpath.html.

this is what I entered in the command line:

C:\Users\k>java -classpath C:\Users\k\Downloads\lucene-3.3.0\contrib\demo\lucene-demo-3.3.0.jar;C:\Users\k\Downloads\lucene-3.3.0\lucene-core-3.3.0.jar

It returns a list of options usable with the java keyword.

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need something along the lines of

```
C:\Users\k>java -classpath C:\Users\k\Downloads\lucene-3.3.0\contrib\demo\lucene-demo-3.3.0.jar;C:\Users\k\Downloads\lucene-3.3.0\lucene-core-3.3.0.jar org.apache.lucene.demo.IndexFiles -docs {path-to-lucene}/src
```

It looks like you set the classpath correctly, all you needed to do after that was `org.apache.lucene.demo.IndexFiles` which tells the JVM which is the main class of the application and  `-docs {path-to-lucene}/src` is an argument passed into the lucene demo.

Answer (score 2):

The command you are using is not for setting class path. It is the `java` command used to run java class file. You are providing it a class path arguments which determines from where to load class files.

To set classpath use this command on windows:

`set CLASSPATH=classpath1;classpath2...`

So if you want to still use java command with -classpath argument then specify a class name at the end of command which is the class going to be run like

```
C:\Users\k>java -classpath C:\Users\k\Downloads\lucene-3.3.0\contrib\demo
   \lucene-demo-3.3.0.jar;C:\Users\k\Downloads\lucene-3.3.0\
    lucene-core-3.3.0.jar MyClassName
```